# Where is the gsm command for emulating calls?

Tags: android, android-emulator

The emulator guide says that calls can be emulated using the gsm command (http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html).

But that command is unrecognized when I try to use it, so presumably I don't have a path set up to it. But where is it? I couldn't find where it actually is located.

(Also the emulator guide says" "You can use the gsm command to access the emulator's telephony functions after connecting to the console.' What does it mean by "connecting to the console"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [connecting to the console section](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#console) of that same document states how to use the console:

> Each running emulator instance provides a console that lets you query and control the emulated device environment. For example, you can use the console to manage port redirection, network characteristics, and telephony events while your application is running on the emulator. To access the console and enter commands, use telnet to connect to the console's port number.
>
> To connect to the console of any running emulator instance at any time, use this command:
>
> `telnet localhost <console-port>`

Where you can get the port number by using `adb devices` while your emulator is running.